# Cakephp login function

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm using CakePHP to create a simple administration panel and I crated login system which show flash message on wrong username or pw.

Can anyone tell me how to make a Cakephp login function which will fadeIn error messages with jQuery (without refreshing whole page like setFlash do), and which will for example fadeIn "loading image or spinner" and after server check for data - if username or pw is wrong - fadeIn error message and if not redirect to dashboard.

Thanks.

Comment: What you need is a tutorial, Stack overflow isn't the right place to ask for that.

Comment: Actually I don't need tutorial I could build it alone but just need instructions for "steps", and which components do I need like ajax helper, js etc...

Comment: you've just described a tutorial :). Have you read [the book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html)?

Comment: got it working using below answer and little research, and yes I checked that in book but it is not explainded in details in the book, as it cover mainly areas so I have to use google + stackoverflow for help.. thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you're not really supposed to come here asking someone to just complete a whole task for you, but I can give you some guidelines.

- You'll need to use AJAX for performing the login. So have your login
  action and post the form to that using AJAX.
- When the form is sent, replace the contents of your page wherever you want with a loading spinner or something. Then have the contents of the AJAX call put into the same place.
- Make the view for the login action have the flash message if login failed (and use jQuery to fade it in, this is done in the view), as well as the original form.
- If the login is successful, simply do a redirect to the dashboard.

As for how to use AJAX, personally I use this helper: http://www.cakephp.4uk.pl/. However there are a few ways you can do it.
Using the helper makes it very easy though, and in your form you'd just need to have a button like this:

```
<?php echo $this->Ajax->submit('Login', array(
    'url'       => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
    'update'    => 'div-for-putting-flashmessage',
    'before'    => 'some_code_to_show_a_spinner_in_the_div'
)); ?>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22147771/php-web-service-for-authenticating-user-login-on-android