# PHP web service for authenticating user login on Android

Tags: php, android, json, post

Trying to get the user authentication work on Android.

The Android app sends username and password using POST method. But, I keep getting "Error receiving detail!!" error. I tried to use REST console to see if the web service works, but no success, I get the same error even there.

Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Have built a PHP web service and the code is:

```
<?php

require_once '../site_info.php';
require_once '../database_connect.php';
require_once '../functions.php';

if(isset($_REQUEST['email']) and $_REQUEST['email']!='' and isset($_REQUEST['password']) and $_REQUEST['password']!='')
{
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['email']);
    $pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['password']);

    $query = 'select id from users where email = "'.$email.'" and password = "'.sha1($pass).'"';
    $result=mysql_query($query) or die('error getting admin details : '.mysql_error());

    if(mysql_num_rows($result)==1)
    {
        echo 'Login Success!!';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Incorrect login details!!';
    }
}
else
{
    echo 'Error recieving data!!';
}

?>
```

The Android app sends request as json:

JOSN request data:{"password":"password","email":"test@gmail.com"}

response

status:200

response body:array(0) {}Error recieving data!!

Comment: Can we see your java based http connection?

Comment: You have taqged this question with json? I do not see anything related to json in your question? Please provide further detail or edit your tags.

Comment: @fieldtech.io I've edited the Question. The Android app sends the request in json format.      `JOSN request data:{"password":"password","email":"test@gmail.com"}`

response

status:200

`response body:array(0) {}Error recieving data!!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution

```
<?php

require_once '../site.php';
require_once '../database.php';
require_once '../functions.php';

$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json = json_decode($data);

$email = $json->{'email'};
$password = $json->{'password'};

if(!empty($email) and !empty($password))
{
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

    $query = 'select id from users where email = "'.$email.'" and password = "'.sha1($password).'"';
    $result=mysql_query($query) or die('error getting admin details : '.mysql_error());

    if(mysql_num_rows($result)==1)
    {
        $array = array("success" => "TRUE");
        print(json_encode($array));
    }
    else
    {
        $array = array("error" => "Login invalid.");
        print( json_encode($array));
    }
}
else
{
    $array = array("error" => "Data not recieved.");
    print( json_encode($array));
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
else{
    var_dump($_REQUEST); //add this line to see what's coming to your script
    echo 'Error recieving data!!';
}
```

If you receive nothing then you can try using something to post on this script to check the script, but I guess the problem comes from the client.

In a command line (assuming you have cURL) :

```
curl --data "param1=value1&param2=value2" http://example.com/script.php
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I see this now  `array(1) {
    ["PHPSESSID"]=>
    string(32) "bc30b82cdaf41cdcbb15c5d57177cfaa"
    }
    Error recieving data!!`

Comment: I'm using REST console to try this out using POST method.  In the body I wrote  email=test@test.com&password=password  Do you suspect any error in the PHP file?

Comment: The problem I think seems to be that the PHP file is not able to read the json request that the Android app is sending. The Android app sends the request as json:

    JOSN request data:{"password":"password","email":"test@gmail.com"}

response

status:200

response body:array(0) {}Error recieving data!!

Comment: Yeah you pinpointed it. My best bet is to urlencode this and pass as a GET parameter to your php script and then use `json_decode()` on it.